# How to validate two forms at once with php

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I have two forms contained in one PHP file. One of the forms is for "log in" and the other form is to "sign up" i have some CSS and JS that will switch out the forms visually, but regardless the two forms are still in one php file.

These forms are standard:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" name="user-sign-up">
 <div class="error">
<?php if(!empty($error)){echo $error;} ?>
</div>
          <span>First name</span>
          <input type="text" name="fname" class="fname">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="signupdawg" id="firstname-signup"> 
</form>
```

Then I got another form underneath that one.

Here's my php, it sort of works and only works for one of the forms:

```
if( isset($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['fname'])){

    $upName = $_POST['fname'];

if(empty($upName)){

        $error = 'All fields are required';
```

I only shortened the code, so it wouldn't take up to much space. I had other inputs like a password, but I just removed it because the code is pretty much the same except I had an "or" in my php empty check and a few more lines in my html for it.

Anyway, I am wondering how I can validate two forms at once with PHP.

Thank you.

Comment: Add a hidden input to each, that denotes which specific form is being submitted. Then key off that for checks and balances.

Comment: Generally its better to have different scripts handle different actions. With classes, includes, and common html outputs, its not a problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "validate two forms at once"?  Are you having trouble determining which form was posted, or are you trying to validate the inputs from both forms at the same time (even though only one of them was actually posted)?  Or something else?

Comment: LOL @ that edit. What a useless change by someone else ;)

Comment: @David the one that was submitted. so i have trouble deterining which form was posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only submit one form at a time, so you need to use something on the form to determine which one was submitted.  This is just a simple example using your code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Sign_Up'])) {
    //do sign up stuff
} 
elseif(isset($_POST['Login'])) {
    //do login stuff
}
```

Notice `Sign Up` is converted to `Sign_Up`.  It may be better to use two separate `action` in each form and have two different files.

Additionally, `isset` is redundant here:

```
if( isset($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['fname'])){
```

The `empty` already checks if it is set, so just:

```
if(!empty($_POST['fname'])){
```

Comment: `$_POST['Sign Up']` is that even allowed? A space in a name from a form post? Hmm... never tried that... just seems so messy :-)

Comment: @IncredibleHat  Yes, though space is converted to `_`.  I agree, just giving an example using existing code.

Comment: @AbraCadaver ah... well I'll be. What, 20 years and I never realized it would do that hahaha I've just always named form fields with only a-z0-9 :D

Comment: @IncredibleHat what can i say, ya learn sumthin new every day eh

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a unique value on the submit button for each form, an example is below
index.html

```
<form method="post" ...>
...
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="login">login</button>
</form>

<form method="post" ...>
   ...
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="sginup">sginup</button>
</form>
```

PHP file

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      switch ($_POST["submit"]) {
          case "login":
                login();
              break;
          case "sginup":
               singup();
              break;
          default: 
              break;
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: actually, you can use the value of any input inside the form it does not need to be the button (ie you can use a hidden input field). but usually, I prefer to use the button